# local storage value on checkout page

Tags: shopify

i have stored value on local Storage in Shopify. but when i went to checkout page it remove value from local Storage. how i can get local storage value at checkout page?

Comment: You need to give more information in order to get help here - we cannot assist you in fixing code that we cannot see

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have your own https domain set up you will be checking out from a different domain. Like cookies LocalStorage is domain dependent and you can only retrieve data from the domain you stored it in. Also because you have only limited control over the checkout you will find it difficult to implement some of the common cross-domain communication strategies.

You are pretty limited as far as affecting the checkout. You can get access to the order again on the Thank You page and script tags from apps should become active again but you will still be on the shopify domain so you cannot get access to any local storage